# Deploying a file to the filesystem using MOSS Solutions and Features

Tags: sharepoint, filesystems, solution

I have a .browser file that I need to deploy to the following location:

c:\browsers\

as part of a moss .wsp file. Can I do this in the manifest.xml or as part of a feature?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You can use the wsp solution to deploy any File to

1. Inside 12 Hive Folder Hierarchy
2. GAC
3. bin Folder of the Web Application.

Rest of the other location you need to look out for the custom solution. One option I can say is to use a Feature Installed event and keep it a Farm Feature.

Comment: I agree - all I can think of is a Feature Installed event.  Not ideal, but you could make the feature scoped to the Farm so it would only be run once.

Comment: Would a feature installed event ensure that the file is installed on all web front ends as that is my main concern. Kind Regards

Comment: When you deploy it as WSP it will be deployed to all the WFE servers. Later you will need to install it in the each of the server, to get the files to place in each of the server.